# Realization of depending attributes

Tags: magento, attributes

Lets say I have a t-shirt in the sizes S and XL. The product is available with no printing and with predefined prints. The additional fee for a shirt with a print is $5 for the small shirt, but its $10 for the big one.

So far I can just set a general additional fee for attributes.
What I am looking for is a way to add this condition (if size=XL then add $10 else add $5)

I created 120 configurable products and already using the super attribute feature. But this lacks on attr who are depend on another one.

```
Shirt size S, no print  $10
Shirt size S, print     $15  (+  $5 for print)
Shirt size XL, no print $20  (+ $10 for size XL)
Shirt size XL, print    $30  (+ $10 for size, + $10 for print)
```

As you see the price for print is $5 for S but $10 for XL.

How I can do that in magento? Is there an extension available?

Answer (score 1):

You would do this through Custom Options.

Or a more detailed roundabout way would be to use super attributes, but thats only if you need to heavily manage inventory, and if you have and inventory system, if this is something you are looking for Linnworks handles magento variations quite well and I have been able to manage many products in different sizes and flavors this way.

But, for you, Custom Options will work fine.

ITEM A Black Shirt
Price $10

Custom Options

Choose a size
Xsmall +$3
Large 0
Xlarge +$6

This will reflect on the front end as, a large black shirt for $10, or which ever custom option you set as default. So then, if you select xsmall the price would update to $13, and so on. Please let me know if this makes sense!

Comment: I just gave a simple example to illustrate my problem. In real I have around 120 products with lots of attributes which will produce ca 7000 variations.

See my updated question.

Comment: Hello my friend. I would say at this point you might investigate linnworks. Their linnlive listing tool will allow you to manage all of your variations with ease. 

http://www.linnworks.com/Doc/magento_multivariation_products_configurable

The link above has more info on how those products are handled in linnworks. If you view this link and find it unsatisfactory for your needs, let me know and I will try to think of a viable solution for you my friend.

Comment: Linnworks indeed solve the problem I described above. But since it is not available for mac or linux natively, this is not an option.